# Coil image caching

Tags: android, image-caching, coil

I load my images into an android app with the Coil library. And it instantly shows me cached images if there is no internet. But when there is an internet connection, the Coil loads images again, and for a while I see the placeholder. I think it's a very strange logic. How can I make it show me the cached images instantly even if there is an internet connection?

My current code:

```
fun ImageView.setPhoto(photoLink: String) {
    load(photoLink) {
        crossfade(true)
        placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
        error(R.drawable.placeholder)
        size(ViewSizeResolver(this@setPhoto))
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure if this is really so strange, isn't placeholder designed to be shown while images are being loaded ?

Comment: why you are not using glide and picasso.These are store images in cache

Comment: @a_local_nobody I mean waiting for loading again. I don't want to load the same image if I have it in the cache.

Comment: @MuhammadAsad Coil is a perfectly viable image library and has both an in-memory and disk cache. I'd even go as far to say it's better than both Picasso and Glide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try disabling the cache headers support.

```
val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(context)
        .respectCacheHeaders(false)
        .build()
Coil.setImageLoader(imageLoader)
```

Comment: Where does this go?

Comment: I did find out that you can do something similar with the ImageLoaderFactory on your Application instance: https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/getting_started/

Comment: @coderforlife, it's not a big deal where to put that, because Coil is a singleton, and changes are applied across the app. I prefer to do that in MainActivity if the app is single activity or in Application class if not